# Why am I getting a fatal error on a script that works in a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I put together the following code to show an CPT with a date filter. If I put the script in wp_config.php it works. It won't work in functions.php. I was reading about a debug method to see if it works in wp_config, but I did not get anywhere besides that it works in there.

I am trying to put it in as a plugin. I get a fatal error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Elementor\Widget_Base" not found in *****/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-widget/my-custom-widget.php:14

````
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Custom Widget
 * Plugin URI:  https://www.website.com/
 * Description: Custom Elementor Widget for displaying events.
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      Ryan 
 * Author URI:  https://www.website.com/
 * Text Domain: my-custom-widget
 */

/** Create Custom Widget*/

class My_Custom_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'my_custom_widget';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return 'Custom Events Widget';
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'eicon-post-list';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'general' ];
    }

    protected function _register_controls() {
        $this->start_controls_section(
            'section_content',
            [
                'label' => 'Settings',
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'custom_post_type',
            [
                'label' => 'Custom Post Type',
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'options' => $this->get_custom_post_types(),
                'default' => 'your_custom_post_type', // Replace with your default CPT slug
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();
    }

    protected function render() {
        $settings = $this->get_settings();

        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $future_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days'));

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $settings['custom_post_type'],
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key' => 'date_of_event', // Replace with your ACF date field key
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'date_of_event', // Replace with your ACF date field key
                    'value' => array($today, $future_date),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type' => 'DATE',
                ),
            ),
        );

        $events = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($events->have_posts()) :
            while ($events->have_posts()) : $events->the_post();
                // Retrieve additional ACF fields and customize the layout as desired
                $event_title = get_the_title();
                $event_permalink = get_permalink();
                $event_date = get_field('date_of_event'); // Replace with your ACF field name
                $event_description = get_field('event_description'); // Replace with your ACF field name
                ?>
                <div class="event">
                    <h4><?php echo $event_date; ?></h4>
                    <h3 style="padding-bottom:10px;"><a href="<?php echo $event_permalink; ?>"><?php echo $event_title; ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="event-description"><?php echo $event_description; ?></div>
                </div>
                <?php
            endwhile;
        else :
            echo 'No events found.';
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    // Helper method to retrieve available custom post types
    private function get_custom_post_types() {
        $post_types = get_post_types(['public' => true], 'objects');
        $options = [];

        foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
            $options[$post_type->name] = $post_type->label;
        }

        return $options;
    }
}

// Register the custom widget with Elementor
function register_custom_widget() {
    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new My_Custom_Widget());
}
add_action('elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', 'register_custom_widget');```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your class is attempting to extend a class that has not yet been loaded. Moving your class definition into a separate file, and then requiring inside of the action callback will work.

Untested:

```php
function register_custom_widget() {
    require_once 'my-custom-widget.php';
    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new My_Custom_Widget() );
}
add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', 'register_custom_widget' );
```

Makes no sense how that would work in `wp-config.php`, but the above should work.